# What lightweight python library for simple scientific visualization in 3D

Tags: python, 3d, geometry, visualization

I am writing a program in python to experiment an academic idea.  Look at a resultant image the program generates:

[image: leaf]

The thick skeleton lines in the middle of the leaf is what need to be visualized.  Every segment of the skeleton lines has a value associated with it, in the above image (drawn by `pycairo`), different shades of gray are used for visualization, the lighter color means higher value, black lines indicate the lines have value 0 associated with them.  The problem is visualization using colors in this case is very unintuitive for human eyes, it would be much better to visualize the values in 3D like the following (taken from a paper):

[image: 2d in 3d]

the left image is a 3D visualization of the right one, the values associated with the lines are visualized as height of consecutive walls in 3D.

What is the best library to do this?  I don't want to invest much time into doing this, so a lightweight library is preferred.

Comment: As a very late suggestion, you display two offset 2D perspective renderings side by side, then performing a free-view stereoscopic visualization (note to myself: trying this soon!). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3d_photography#Side-by-side_.28non-shared_viewing_scenarios.29

Answer (score 5):

If you want lightweight, then you can use [PyOpenGL](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/) to just wrap OpenGL calls in python directly.  This is probably the lightest-weight option.

If you want lots of features, I'd recommend using [VTK](http://vtk.org/).  It's a very powerful visualization toolkit with Python wrappers (included).  There are other packages built on top of this (such as Mayavi and Paraview), but the VTK wrappers alone are often easier to use.  This would probably be my first choice, since they have some good samples you can use - all you'd need to do is make a VtkPolyData instance, and throw it in a renderer.

That being said, for ease of development, you might want something that simplifies this for you, such as wrappers for a light-weight rendering engine like [Irrlicht](http://irrlicht.sourceforge.net/links.html) via [Pyrr](https://opensvn.csie.org/traccgi/pyrr).  This makes it much easier to generate the picture.

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at [mayavi](http://code.enthought.com/projects/mayavi/)?  Don't know if it meets your definition of "lightweight", but it does seem popular and reasonably easy to use for its power.

Comment: I have used mayavi months ago for a different project, its workflow and pipeline are quite complicated, may be overskill for this.

Comment: This is basically a wrapper for VTK - probably easier to just use VTK directly.

Comment: There is a enthought.mayavi.mlab module which provides a simple interface to the library. The function calls resemble the matlab 3d plot functions.